# Sending form fields not related to passed model: Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model

I am using a form_for loop to submit data to my controller’s create method. In the form_for I have several text_fields that are not associated to any field on the table. They are essentially free text fields that I want to put data in and use for additional logic in the create method.

When I submit the form, the first line of the create is hit:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

The following error occurs (:test1 being my form field unrelated to the model):

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: test1
```

I realize it is because of the text fields I’m sending that are not related to the model. I have tried all sorts of strange syntaxes such as:

`User.new(params.require(:user).except(:test1))` and `User.new(params[:user].except(:test1))` to no avail.

I’ve found several sources online stating you can use the except or delete method but I can’t seem to get it to work, especially while in the User.new().

I have tried it outside the new as well:

```
params.delete(:test1)
@user = User.new(params[:xref_ability])
```

I also want to be able to read the additional attributes eventually in the create, so I don’t think the except() or delete() is going to solve all my issues (if it did work). Therefore, I tried attr_accessor :test1 on the controller class and the model class hoping it would give the method permission to read the attribute, but no success.

I've also tried adding it to attr_accessible on my model which then leads to the error:

```
unknown attribute: test1
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using virtual attributes? It makes sense to use them if they don't map to a field in the DB.

RB has a good railscast on the topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I had previously tried one or the other, but not both. I believe it is key to use `attr_accesor` first, then `attr_accessible`. I also found this link helpful: http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/how-create-create-a-virtual-attribute-in-rails/

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a `attr_accessible :test1` on your User model, give it a try.

Comment: as I stated, when I try that on my User model, it leads to the error `unknown attribute: test1`

Comment: If you actually don't have this attr in the database you need a `attr_accessor :test1` line in your model indeed as @zapico mentioned, if you do have the attr in the database you don't need the attr_accessor.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the unknown attribute error because it doesn't exist in the database.

You must create test1 in database (add it with a migration...) or just add it to your model with:

```
attr_accessor :test1
```

This way you'll have the value in the object but it won't store in the database. If you need to store it, add it to the database and use attr_accessible as @Miguelgraz told you before.